# Java log4j doesn't always log the last line

Tags: java, command-line, log4j, output

I have a testing program (that I didn't write) that is giving a very weird error, which only happens some of the time. At the end of the program a string that contains the test report is output using

```
logger.warn(reportString);
```

Anywhere from 1/10 to 1/3 tries (it varies) this string isn't being displayed, but everything before it is.
Before this I added this line to ensure that the string is always created properly, which it is since this gives the same length every time.

```
logger.info("Length: " + reportString.length());
```

To experiment I added another logging line after, so the end of the program now looks like this:

```
logger.info("Length: " + reportString.length());
logger.warn(reportString);
logger.info("REACHED END OF PROGRAM");
```

When doing this the reportString always seems to be printed/logged, but the "REACHED END OF PROGRAM" string is only printed/logged about 50% of the time. Maybe it's something with my windows command prompt? I know this is a pretty vague problem but if anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a threading issue.  A threading issue where you are not calling `join` somewhere.

Comment: Threads are used in the program, so I will check that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to flush the all buffered logs to send all to the output. Add the next:

```
logger.warn(reportString);
LogManager.shutdown();
```

Just in case you have it in your code, you can try removing the sentence:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. I noticed the program uses some special log4j settings, such as an AsyncAppender. So it might have had something to do with threads like the comment above said.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with how log4j buffers the data it outputs, try explicitly adding \n in the last string the logger prints, and see if it prints consistently now.